# About 'Hybrid Types', why use ': interface name' will report an error

Tags: typescript

Novice problem, Why can't I use the second method?

```
interface Counter {
 (start: number): string;
 interval: number;
 reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  1. let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { return '123' };

  2. let counter: Counter = function (start: number) { return '123' };

  counter.interval = 123;
  counter.reset = function () { };

  return counter;
}
```

The second method will prompt 'Type '(start: number) => string' is missing the following properties from type 'Counter': interval, reset'. What is the difference between them?